# How to count records in sqlite db table using moor_flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor

How do I count all rows in a table and get number of rows as a result using the [moor_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/moor_flutter) package?

I have seen moor_flutter official documentation [here](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/) but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I was hoping it would be like the function below according to the similarities in crud functions when using the moor_flutter package but it is not working either.

```dart
Future<int<Person>> countPersons() => count(persons).get();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I figured out a way to find count of table rows. Here is a complete solution with basic comments,

```
//Create expression of count
var countExp = persons.id.count();

//Moor creates query from Expression so, they don't have value unless you execute it as query.  
//Following query will execute experssion on Table.
final query = selectOnly(persons)..addColumns([countExp]);
var result = await query.map((row) => row.read(countExp)).getSingle();
```

Please note that I have used `selectOnly` instead of `select` because I am not interested in any column except Count.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a filter condition on your count, then you can put call the top level function `countAll` with the named parameter `filter` as you can see below.

```
var count = countAll(filter: persons.id.isSmallerThanValue(100));
var res = await (selectOnly(persons)..addColumns([count]))
    .map((row) => row.read(count))
    .getSingle();
```

It is now documented in [the official documentation](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#counting)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Now, count expression is supported by moor, see [this link](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#counting) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64118556/10122791).

This answer is ***not*** a way to go anymore, because of obvious performance issues.

---

<s>There is no such statement in `moor_flutter` (only `select`, `into`, `update` and `delete`).</s>

This should work :

```dart
Future<int> countPersons() async {
    return (await select(persons).get()).length;
}
```

or (exactly the same but one line)

```dart
Future<int> countPersons() async => (await select(persons).get()).length;
```

Or you could try to [write custom SQL queries](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/starting_with_sql/).

Comment: This is very bad, it will load entire list of records before getting the count

Comment: At the moment it was the only way to perform a count without writing custom SQL queries. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical Moor way seems a trifle confusing to me.  If you feel the same, you might go old school and try:

```
@UseDao(
  tables: [Instruments],
  queries: {
    'instrumentsCount': 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM instruments;'
  },
)
```

Comment: Could you explain how to use this? Or give us more of the code. I cannot figure out this syntax.

Comment: @M.Azyoksul Moor allow you to put any SQL statement into a queries parameter.  This is the full code for it, i.e. return the number of rows in the instruments table.  I'm not sure which bit is causing you problems, I'm afraid:  see an SQL reference for the statement, or the Moor reference for the UseDao parameter?

Comment: @M.Azyoksul For a better explanation you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68510058/1318946

Answer (score -1):

final numberOfPersons = persons.id.count();

[It is supported in moor 2.4](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/getting-started/expressions/#aggregate)

Comment: It returns an `Expression`. Is there a way to get `int` out of it?

Comment: @ChiragMittal found any answer for this? how to get int from expression?

Comment: @Iducool Nope. I just went on to get a list of all objects and evaluate the size. Obviously I won't recommend this workaround. If you find anything better, please post here.